# Applying min-height to List item

Tags: html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap theme with Laravel framework and I'm experiencing issues allowing a list item to increase height based on its contents.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h66br41p/

I have changed:

```
.framemail .window .mail li i {
display: inline-block;
height: 70px;
width: 6px;
}
```

To:

```
.framemail .window .mail li i {
display: inline-block;
min-height: 70px;
width: 6px;
}
```

This is producing no difference. It is still the fixed height of 70px regardless of contents.

here is any other css targeting this area:

```
.framemail .window .mail li {
background-color:#3d3d3d;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.05), hsla(0,0%,0%,.05));
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.05), hsla(0,0%,0%,.05));
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.05), hsla(0,0%,0%,.05));
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.05), hsla(0,0%,0%,.05));
background-image:         linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.05), hsla(0,0%,0%,.05));
border-top: 1px solid #888;
position: relative;
margin-left:-18px;
}

.framemail .window .mail li:first-child {
border-top: none;
}

.framemail .window .mail li:hover {
background-color: #5d5b5b;
}

.framemail .window .mail li:after,
.framemail .window .mail li:before {
border-left: 8px solid transparent;
content: '';
height: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 0;
}

.framemail .window .mail li i {
display: inline-block;
height: 70px;
width: 6px;
}

.framemail .window .mail li .read {
background-color: #ddd;
}

.framemail .window .mail li .unread {
background: #b2c831;
}

.framemail .window .mail li img {
border-radius: 2px;
height: 36px;
left: 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
width: 36px;
}

.framemail .window .mail li p {
font: 13px sans-serif;
left: 56px;
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="mail">
                    <li>
                        <i class="unread"></i>
                        <img src="/assets/img/logo80x80.png" alt="avatar">
                        <p class="sender">Dashboard</p>
                        <p class="message">You have been successfully verified<br>Clipping<br>Clipping</p>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <a><img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files//icons/2232/wireframe_mono/16/trash.png" alt="delete"></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="unread"></i>
                        <img src="/assets/img/logo80x80.png" alt="avatar">
                        <p class="sender">Dashboard</p>
                        <p class="message">You have been successfully verified</p>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <a><img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files//icons/2232/wireframe_mono/16/trash.png" alt="delete"></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

[image]
I wish for these to list items to resize based on the text inside. What is making them fixed?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show that a row needs to be any taller than 70px.  Do you have an example of the text clipping?  Possibly would help... granted, seeing the HTML + CSS in a working demo (fiddle) would make it even easier.

Comment: Sure, original post updated, with two extra lines of 'clipping' added. I will see what I can do about the JSfiddle

Comment: Just remove min-height and add padding-top, padding-bottom to get padded from borders.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h66br41p/

Comment: Update on answer. Latest elements you can now styling as you wish. Or if you want to use absolute positions, then search a JQ plugin that grabs a text content height and put in to parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `min-height` and add `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` to get padded from borders. In this design you dont need to make a min-height, or fixed heigh of content blocks.

Then you need make a two parts:

Remove any position absolute elements and make a float left and right. Atfer floating create a clear both. The fiddle demo need all to be replaced.

Here is update on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rrzm6y6/2/) Update

Comment: Doing this squashes everything together.

Comment: Update fiddle link to unread line height. Rest you do it selft :)